# How is the pyplot histogram bins interpreted?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I am confused about the matplotlib hist function.

The documentation explains:

> If a sequence of values, the values of the lower bound of the bins to be used.

But when I have two values in sequence i.e [0,1], I only get 1 bin. 
And when I have three like so:

```
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0,1,2], normed=True)
```

I only get two bins. My guess is that the last value is just an upper bound for the last bin.

**Is there a way to have "the rest" of the values in the last bin, other than to but a very big value there? (or in other words, without making that bin much bigger than the others)**

It seems like the last bin value is included in the last bin

```
votes = [0,0,1,2]
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0,1])
```

This gives me one bin of height 3. i.e. 0,0,1. 
While:

```
votes = [0,0,1,2]
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0,1,2])
```

Gives me two bins with two in each. 
I find this counter intuative, that adding a new bin changes the widthlimits of the others.

```
votes = [0,0,1]
plit.hist[votes, bins=2)
```

yeilds two bins size 2 and 1. These seems to have been split on 0,5 since the x-axis goes from 0 to 1.

**How should the bins array be interpreted? How is the data split?**

Comment: What version of `mpl` are you using?  There was a change in `numpy`'s hist function a while ago that changed the meaning of the `bins` a bit, it is important to make sure you are looking at documentation that matches the versions you are using.

Comment: I am using version 1.6.1. Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
votes = [0, 0, 1, 2]
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0,1])
```

this gives you one bin of height 3, because it splits the data into one single bin with the interval: [0, 1]. It puts into that bin the values: 0, 0, and 1.

```
votes = [0, 0, 1, 2]
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0, 1, 2])
```

this gives you an histogram with bins with intervals: [0, 1[ and [1, 2];
so you have 2 items in the 1st bin (the 0 and 0), and 2 items in the 2nd bin (the 1 and 2).

If you try to plot:

```
plt.hist(votes, bins=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

the idea behind the data splitting into bins is the same:
you will get three intervals:
[0, 1[; [1, 2[; [2, 3], and you will notice that the value 2 changes its bin, going to the bin with interval [2, 3] (instead of staying in the bin [1, 2] as in the previous example).

In conclusion, if you have an ordered array in the bins argument like:
[i_0, i_1, i_2, i_3, i_4, ..., i_n]
that will create the bins:
[i_0, i_1[
[i_1, i_2[
[i_2, i_3[
[i_3, i_4[
...
[i_(n-1), i_n]

with the boundaries of each open or closed according to the brackets.

Comment: Another way to make this clear/behave better, is to subtract `0.5` from your bin edges (if you expect the values in `votes` to be integers) so you can side step these details about open/closed sets.

Comment: also +1 for super clear explanation of the details of the open/closed set issue.